# is there a numpy function to delete elements in two arrays given a condition?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have two arrays:

```
a = np.array([0.0, 3.0, 5.0, 0.0, 10.0])
b = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0 ])
```

I want to delete elements equal to 0.0 from both lists and the non-zero elements which are in the same position of a deleted 0.0 element in the other list. Exactly, what I expect is:

```
a = np.array([5.0, 10.0])
b = np.array([1.0, 1.0 ])
```

thanks!

Comment: It's best to think in terms of what elements you want to keep.  There is `np.delete`, but under the covers it still makes a new array with 'keep' elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
a = np.array([0.0, 3.0, 5.0, 0.0, 10.0])
b = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.0, 1.0 ])

mask = ~((a == 0) | (b == 0))

a = a[mask]
b = b[mask]

print(a)
print(b)
```

Prints:

```
[ 5. 10.]
[1. 1.]
```